# Creating a file server so I can access it from anywhere

Tags: remote-access, server, ftp, http, raspberry-pi

I'm a filmmaker/video editor and I'm often in the situation where I'm on location and I have my laptop and I want to edit on the go, but all my files are at home. 
I'm wanting to create a file server hosted on a rasbery pi that is plugged into my nas or somehow has access to my pc files, and then i want to be able to connect over the intenet and pull the files i need. and also have sync capabilities.

I use GoodSync for my backups, and noticed it has the ability to sync over FTP, so this would work great. I work on a windows pc/laptop.

I'm thinking FTP would be easiest to setup on the rasberry pi ? (not that I've ever done it before or even know how to...). Is it easy to set this up, as well as any necessary port forwarding and ddns shenanigans I have to do to my consumer router?

Is there a better protocol I should be looking into rather then ftp? such as HTTP? I'd love to be able to create a VPN but my router doesn't allow it.

I really appricate any advice!
Cheers,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

have you considered MEGA? (https://mega.nz/) It all depends of the size of what you want to serve. But regardless of that, raspberry pi will not give you the speed over network, reliability, or capacity of a dedicated service like MEGA, I always recommend MEGA because they offer 50GB free and their security is top-notch, they even had some issues with the government about this in the past because they have very restricted backdoors (if any). They have software clients for any platform that you can imagine, even for iOS and Android. You can also go for another service like Dropbox or Google Drive but they will give you a very limited free space. If 50GB is enough, go for it, thay also have paid plans with more storage. Let me know what you end up using, I'm always searching for new exiting tools and software to use.

Comment: Hey @Carlos,
I do have Google Drive and I pay for 1TB and I mainly use that to send files to clients. While i do like it, I don't feel it is a great solution for big files. Downloading large amounts of files is unstable and feels very slow. I'm sure this is what most major cloud provides feel like to use, incuding MEGA. As a film editor I working with multipe TB of files, so these plans get very costly on a yearly basis.

Comment: I did manage to get an FTP server running on my windows machine, and set up a ddns, ddns updater and portforwading so now i have access to my files anywhere! I want to migrate this to my raspberry pi once it arrives and get a SATA to USB3.0 to attatch my 6tb backup drive to it. I'm then thinking of running ethernet from the PI straight into my gigabit switch, mount the drive on my PC (not sure how to do this yet) and setup a daily sync to keep my drives on my PC mirrored to the backup drive on the pi (using good sync probably).

Comment: Then my ftp server has access to the backup drive which is essentally the files on my PC. Then i can work off my laptop remotely, sync my files back to the ftp, then my pc will automatically sync all the new files from the backup drive so everything is kept up to date and no need for manually copying files! I was getting around 1.5Mb/s down on the ftp from my PC. Before I head out to do remote work I can sync the files i need down to my laptop locally so its nice and fast too.